# How would I merge these two dataframes to produce the third dataframe in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having difficulty joining these two dataframe views because of not being able to modify specific column values in spark scala. I think I have to do a transpose/join somehow, but am not able to figure it out.

Here is the first dataframe:

```
  var sample_df = Seq(("john","morning","7am"),("john","night","10pm"),("bob","morning","8am"),("bob","night","11pm"),("phil","morning","9am"),("phil","night","10pm")).toDF("person","time_of_day","wake/sleep hour")
```

[image]

here is the second dataframe:

```
  var sample_df2 = Seq(("john","6am","11pm"),("bob","7am","2am"),("phil","8am","1am")).toDF("person","morning_earliest","night_latest")
```

[image]

and here is the resulting dataframe I'm looking to produce:

```
  var resulting_df = Seq(("john","morning","7am","6am"),("john","night","10pm","11pm"),("bob","morning","8am","7am"),("bob","night","11pm","2am"),("phil","morning","9am","8am"),("phil","night","10pm","1am")).toDF("person","time_of_day","wake/sleep hour","earliest/latest")
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks and have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sample_df.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
sample_df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

spark.sql("""
select person, time_of_day, `wake/sleep hour`, `earliest/latest`
from (
    select person, stack(2, 'morning', morning_earliest, 'night', night_latest) as (time_of_day, `earliest/latest`)
    from df2
) df
join df1
using (time_of_day, person)
""").show()

+------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|person|time_of_day|wake/sleep hour|earliest/latest|
+------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|  john|    morning|            7am|            6am|
|  john|      night|           10pm|           11pm|
|   bob|    morning|            8am|            7am|
|   bob|      night|           11pm|            2am|
|  phil|    morning|            9am|            8am|
|  phil|      night|           10pm|            1am|
+------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```scala
val df = sample_df
    .join(sample_df2,"person")

val resulting_df = df.withColumn("earliest/latest",
    when(col("time_of_day")=== "morning", $"morning_earliest")
    .otherwise($"night_latest"))
    .drop($"morning_earliest")
    .drop($"night_latest")

resulting_df.show()
```